# Show $Y$ converges to $a$

Tags: self-study, density-function, convergence

Given:
$f_{Y_{(1)}}(y) = nbe^{-nb(y-a)}$, where $b> 0$ and $y \geq a$.

Show that as $n \rightarrow\infty$, $Y_{(1)}$ converges to $a$ in probability.

I have calculated $E[Y_{(1)}] = \frac{1}{nb} + a$

Which theorem should I apply to show convergence. I was trying to use Chebyshev's inquality.

[EDIT]

If I want to find to what $Y_{(1)}$ converges in distribution, is this the right way to do it:

$F_{Y_{(1)}} = 1-e^{-nb(y-a)}$

As $n \rightarrow \infty $

$F_{Y_{(1)}} = 1, y < a$

$F_{Y_{(1)}} = 0, y \geq a$

$P(|Y_{(1)}|< y) = P(|Y_{(1)}|< \epsilon)$ [replacing $y$ with $\epsilon$] = $1-e^{-nb(\epsilon-a)}$

As $n \rightarrow \infty $

$P(|Y_{(1)}|< y) \rightarrow 1$; So $ Y_{(1)} \rightarrow Y$ in distribution. So the limiting distribution is degenerate.

Please let me know if this approach is correct.

Comment: Do you know some other inequalities? Do you know the definition of convergence in probability?

Comment: @Glen_b I used the definition of convergence, and was able to come up with solution. $P(|Y_{(1)} - \mu| > \epsilon) $= $P(|Y_{(1)} - (\frac{1}{nb} + a)| > \epsilon)$ = $P(|Y_{(1)} - a| > \epsilon + \frac{1}{nb})$ . As $n \rightarrow \inf$, $P(|Y_{(1)} - a| > \epsilon + 0) \rightarrow  0$ which implies that $Y_{(1)} \rightarrow a $

Comment: I think the general sort of idea there is along the right kinds of line, but you have to take care with the details.

Comment: @Glen_b I did not understand, what details am I missing. Also, I  have to find to what $Y_{(1)}$ will converge to. I have posted my work underneath the question. Could you please review it.

Comment: While in the limit for $Y_{(1)}$ is degenerate, as you say, you can do even more, like work out the limiting distribution of $nY(1)$. It's probably easiest to work with the case $a=0$ and [generalize from the outcome of that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Distribution_of_the_minimum_of_exponential_random_variables). [So we can not only talk about $Y_{(1)}$ approaching a constant value in the limit but about its behavior on the way.] ... As for care with the details, I meant only the precise details of how one writes limits, and so on. Just take care with each step.

Comment: @Glen_b Can I say that $Y_{(1)} \rightarrow a$ in distribution.

Comment: If you take a look at the example discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Definition) you might see a way to put the argument.

Comment: As Glen_b says, you need to take care of a lot of the details.  For example, it is _not_ true that that the CDF of $Y_{(1)}$ has value $1$ for $y < a$ and value $0$ for $y \geq a$; CDFs are non-decreasing functions.

Answer (score 2):

Fix $\varepsilon\gt 0$. We have $\mathbb P\{|Y^{(1)}_n-a|\geqslant \varepsilon\}=\mathbb P\{Y_n^{(1)}\geqslant a+\varepsilon\}$ (this because the density of $Y^{(1)}_n$ is supported on $[a,\infty)$, hence $\mathbb P\{Y^{(1)}_n\lt a\}=0$).

We can compute $\mathbb P\{a\leqslant Y_n^{(1)}\leqslant a+\varepsilon\}$ thanks to the expression of the density:
$$\mathbb P\{Y_n^{(1)}\leqslant a+\varepsilon\}=\int_{a+\varepsilon}^\infty bne^{-nb(y-a)}\mathrm dy=\int_{a+\varepsilon}^\infty bn{e}^{-nbt}\mathrm dt=[-e^{-nbt}]_{a+\varepsilon}^\infty=e^{-nb(a+\varepsilon)},$$
and this goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score -2):

You have $E[Y_{(1)}] = \frac{1}{nb} + a$.

$Lim_{n->\infty} = \frac{1}{\infty} + a$